Wiegen versus einwiegen
This sentence appears in Der Anschlag by Stephen King, translated by Wolf Bergner:

Am folgenden Tag mietete ich mein altes Apartment in der Harris Avenue, und statt mich wachzuhalten, wiegte der Lärm der landenden Flugzeuge mich sogar in den Schlaf.

Here is the original English sentence:

The following day I rented my old apartment on Harris Avenue, and far from keeping me awake, the sound of the descending planes actually lulled me to sleep.

The use of wiegen in this sentence does not appear to me to be consistent with either DWDS or Duden, because both restrict the use to an actual motion back and forth or rocking, which is not found in this sentence, except for

sich in einer Vorstellung wiegen

which is also not consistent with the sentence since this usage concerns an idea and also the case is wrong -- in den Schlaf, and not, in dem Schlaf.
Einwiegen, on the other hand, would seem to be suitable since both the definitions in DWDS and Duden are consistent with the desired meaning and the case is right.
My question is, is the usage of wiegen correct here, or would einwiegen be the correct choice?
DWDS offers einwiegen: jmdn beschwichtigen, which would appear to me to be a nearly exact translation of the English meaning. Why would the translator choose wiegen over einwiegen, then?

I think you missed the definition in DWDS: https://www.dwds.de/wb/wiegen#d-2-1

No, I saw the definition. It appeared to call for movement.

@ccprog - I think the question is still valid. The original English says nothing about babies, cradles, or rocking, so the German is somewhat more "creative" than I'd expect. Would "lullen" work here? In any case, no translation is exact, and it's often necessary to take a few liberties to get a version that people will want to read. Translations are written for people who want to read the book in their own language, not language learners.

@RDBury -- all true, but how does that help me understand how to use these 2 words?

@RDBury: "lullen" and especially "einlullen" are common German words which describe exactly what "einwiegen" is supposed to mean - "to bring to sleep/rest". The difference is that "einwiegen" expicitly names the "wiegen" - the rocking to and fro - as the means to bring to sleep whereas "einlullen" can be done by other soothing activities.

@bakunin - Thanks for the clarification. English Wiktionary just says "to lull" under "lullen", which isn't very helpful. German Wiktionary has a bunch of meanings listed, but the relevant one is "jemanden (meist Kleinkinder) mit beruhigenden Worten oder Gesang in den Schlaf bringen." DWDS says pretty much the same thing, so it appeared that there has to be singing, or at least speaking involved. I wasn't sure if the sound of airplanes would count as singing; maybe it depends on how literal you want to be.

I hope, some vocabulary can help here:



English
German
word type




the cradle (baby's bed)
die Wiege
noun


the scales (device to measure weights)
die Waage
noun


to cradle someone (to rock, to sway a person)
jemanden wiegen
verb


to weight someone/something (to measure a person's or an object's weight)
jemanden/etwas wiegen
verb


to weight in something (gradually add or remove small portions of a substance to/from a container placed on a scale until the desired weight is reached)
etwas einwiegen
verb


to lull someone to sleep
jemanden einwiegen (outdating and rare; you need to understand it, but don't actively use it)
verb


to lull someone to sleep
jemanden in den Schlaf wiegen (modern German; use this instead)
verb



So if you want to translate "lull someone to sleep", you could use the German of 1850 or so and write "jemanden einwiegen", but that would not be interpreted in the desired way by readers in the 21st century.
The alternative is to use the commonly known and quite frequently used idiom »jemanden in den Schlaf wiegen«, which originally has the meaning »rocking and swaying someone until they fall asleep«, but this rocking motion is not the core of the meaning. The core is »to put someone to sleep«, and if the context doesn't provide a rocking motion, then it's fine. The context provides another cause for the sleepiness (the sound of airplanes descending), which is perfectly fine. We call that process of transferring an original meaning to something else a figurative meaning.

Wiegen
"wiegen" is correct in the context of "sleeping". "In den Schlaf wiegen" refers to a baby in a cradle (eine Wiege) being rocked gently by the parents until the baby falls asleep. "wiegen" is "rocking (the cradle)", therefore you can say "in den Schlaf wiegen" is an idiom, a figure of speech.
"Wiegen" can also be used in the context of "making yourself/someone illusions about a situation", "falsely believing a situation is save" for example ("sich in (falscher) Sicherheit wiegen", "jemanden in Sicherheit wiegen" - this is like "jemanden beschwichtigen, dass etwas sicher ist, obwohl es nicht stimmt", "jemanden in falschem Glauben wiegen").
"Wiegen" also applies in the context of "weighing something": "Ein Kilogramm Mehl abwiegen", "Eine Menge Wasser wiegen", "Ich wiege 80 Kilogramm", "Ich wiege mich jeden Morgen".
Einwiegen
"einwiegen" only refers to the context of weighing something with a scale (einer Waage).
The term "einwiegen" is very uncommon in german. In fact I hear it the first time as a verb. It sounds strange to a point were doubt rises if this is even a valid word.
The noun "Einwaage" is more familiar though (in the context of the amount of food in a can or jar: "Die Einwaage in einem Glas Marmelade ist 200 Gramm", "Die Fisch-Einwaage in einer Dose ist 100 Gramm" etc.).
"Einwiegen" might refer to the process of calibrating a scale until it is ready to use, but other words are far more common for this:  "einrichten" (initialize), "einstellen" (setup): "Ich muss die Waage noch einwiegen/einstellen bevor wir sie benutzen können".
I checked and found that "einwiegen" was indeed an old form of the meaning "putting a baby to sleep". But as RDBury mentioned in the comments, it has lost that meaning since the 1700s already. So "einwiegen" in the context of "going to sleep" is not applicable today anymore.

I think the Wortverlaufskurve in DWDS tells the story. The frequency of "einwiegen: has been declining since the 1700's.

That's an interesting point, but I do not see how it pertains to my question, "Has wiegen been misused in this sentence?" If you are saying that the sentence applies a standard German usage to the word, I just do not see how that opinion squares with the definitions in DWDS/Duden.

DWDS gives this definition for einwiegen:  übertragen jmdn. beschwichtigen. That, I believe, would be an exact translation of the English meaning.

I integrated my comment into the answer. Hope this makes things clear(er).

I think "einwiegen" is still used in sports, in boxing/Judo/fighting/weight lifting with body weight classes: the competitors are weighted before the fight to ensure they are not surpassing the maximum weight. Maybe there are also horse races (even car races?) where horses or cars get additional sand bags to ensure that underweight jockeys or cars don't get artificial advantage, such that the horses and cars have to pull the same load.

"wiegen" are in fact two different words which share a common infinitive form in German. One is of strong declension, the other one weak:

wiegen - wiegte - gewiegt: to gently rock someone (or yourself) to and fro
wiegen - wog - gewogen: to measure a weight / to have a certain weight

An example for the first meaning would be (Hannes Wader, Es ist an der Zeit):

Weit in der Champagne im Mittsommergrün,
dort wo zwischen Grabkreuzen Mohnblumen blüh'n,
da flüstern die Gräser und wiegen sich leicht
im Wind, der sanft über das Gräberfeld streicht.


Far in the Champagne in midsummer green
where poppy flowers bloom between grave crosses
there the grasses whisper and shake themselves effortlessly
in the wind, which gently sweeps over the graveyard

There is, derived from this meaning also the noun "die Wiege" (cradle).
An example for the other meaning (to measure a or have a certain weight) is the biblical proverb, going back to Belshazzar's feast, Dan 5 (the "writing on the wall"):

gewogen und für zu leicht befunden
weighed and found wanting

The strong word can - analogously to English "to weigh" - be used with the meaning "measure a weight" (with an Akkusativobjekt) or "have a (certain) weight".

Ich wiege das Fahrzeug.
Ich wiege 50 kg.

The first one is: I weigh the vessel, the second means I weigh 50 kg. The English usage of "to weigh" in the first meaning is reduced to technical contexts, which is not the case in German.
From these two base meanings can phrases and idioms be derived:

sich in einer Vorstellung wiegen

Means to have a certain (mis-)conception and delight in this (like a baby delights in the cradle). This picture is used mostly to contrast it with a possible harsh clash with reality where the delightful misconception is replaced by the less delightful truth. There is also

jemand/sich in [trügerischer] Sicherheit wiegen

This means to lull someone (oneself) in a [false] sense of security.
As is common with German words (especially nouns and verbs) many compounds can be built from them and in fact are built in this case:

einwiegen

can be built from either form of "wiegen": the one derived from the weak verb means to rock to and fro in order to bring to sleep - to lull someone, especially a baby.
The one derived from the strong verb means to very exactly measure a quantity. The word is mostly used in the context of laboratories and only rarely outside, although the derived oun "Einwage" exists, which describes ("net weight", "weight before tinned") a quantity of a base product used to make something in the context of cooking. For instance you might find the word "Fruchteinwaage" on the label of jelly: it means the net amount of fruit which has gone into the product.
